# return type of GADT evaluator

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm a bit at a loss as to why the last pattern in prodV in the following doesn't work:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data V a where
  V0 :: Float -> V Float
  Vn :: [Float] -> V [Float]

prodV :: (Num a) => V a -> V a -> a
prodV (V0 x) (V0 y) =  x * y
-- prodV (Vn x) (Vn y) = zipWith (*) x y -- this one works
prodV (Vn xs) (Vn ys) = [ sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys ]
prodV (V0 n) (Vn ys) = map (* n) ys
```

GHCi 7.8.3 complains:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Float’ with ‘[Float]’ 
Inaccessible code in
  a pattern with constructor
    Vn :: [Float] -> V [Float],
  in an equation for ‘prodV’
In the pattern: Vn ys`
```

Any pointers? thanks in advance

Comment: For one thing, you expect your function `prodV` to work for all `Num` types, but the `V0` and `Vn` constructors specifically contain `Float`.  Secondly, you're saying that the `a` in `V a` has to be a `Num`, but `Num a => [a]` is not an instance of `Num`.  Looks like you're approaching this problem the wrong way.

Comment: You could certainly write a function like `unV :: V a -> a` that simply unwraps the constructors, but the premise of your function is not correct it seems.  Maybe you should consider `Vn :: [Float] -> V Float`, but that would make `unV :: V a -> a` impossible unless you convert your list of `Float`s to a single `Float` in some fashion first.

Comment: the error remains even if I remove the Num constraint;  I don't quite understand why the V0 and Vn constructors can't be 'mixed'..

Comment: @ocramz `V0 n` has type `V Float` while `Vn ns` has type `V [Float]`. They're not the same types, but you specified that they must be the same, in the type for `prodV`. Pattern matching on GADT constructors refine the types.

Comment: Your function needs to use `Num` functions like `*` and `sum`, so you specified in your type signature that you want `Num a => V a`.  But both constructors to `V` are existential, they can't just hold any type of value.  The values contained in `V0` and `Vn` aren't just any `Num a => a`, they have to have a specific type.  You can't construct a value using `V0` with anything other than a `Float`.  Similarly, `Vn` must be constructed with a value of type `[Float]`.  You're trying to tell the compiler that for `V0 x` and `Vn y`, `x` and `y` have the same type, but by definition they can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature

```
prodV :: (Num a) => V a -> V a -> a
```

mandates that both arguments have the same type parameter, but if you match on `V0` and `Vn` the arguments would have to have the types `V Float` and `V [Float]` in which the type parameter does not match.

I'm not quite sure what you want the semantics to be but I'm guessing that you want to define the GADT as something like

```
data V n where
  V0 :: n -> V n
  Vn :: [n] -> V n
```

and your function as either

```
prodV :: (Num a) => V a -> V a -> V a
prodV (V0 x) (V0 y) =  V0 $ x * y
prodV (Vn xs) (Vn ys) = Vn $ zipWith (*) xs ys
prodV (V0 n) (Vn ys) = Vn $ map (* n) ys
```

or possibly

```
prodV' :: (Num a) => V a -> V a -> a
prodV' (V0 x) (V0 y) =  x * y
prodV' (Vn xs) (Vn ys) = sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys
prodV' (V0 n) (Vn ys) = sum $ map (* n) ys
```

Can you describe what you would like the function `prodV` to actually do? The types in your original code don't really make sense to me as they are.

Answer (score 2):

Well, GHC tells you exactly what the problem is. From your definition, `V0 something` always has the type `V Float` (and `something` should be of type `Float` — but that's not relevant here), while `Vn anything` always has the type `V [Float]`. But the type signature for `prodV` specifies that both have the same type `V a`. So, in this case `a` should be `Float` and `[Float]` at the same time, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to understand how to overload functions in order to mimic algebraic shorthand, but I guess this isn't the right avenue. 
What would the idiomatic Haskell way to do this? E.g. from [Numeric.Matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.1.3/src/src/Numeric/Matrix.hs):

```
adaptScalar f1 f2 f3 x y
    | dim x == 1 = f1   (x@>0) y
    | dim y == 1 = f3 x (y@>0)
    | otherwise = f2 x y

instance Num (Vector Float) where
    (+) = adaptScalar addConstant add (flip addConstant)
    negate = scale (-1)
    (*) = adaptScalar scale mul (flip scale)
    signum = vectorMapF Sign
    abs = vectorMapF Abs
    fromInteger = fromList . return . fromInteger
```

picks the right implementation of the operator (e.g. + or *) according to the dimension of the operands.

Comment: Posting an answer to your own question is not a good way of updating the question. Either ask a new question or edit your original one.